# Paypal Payments Pro give 'Internal service Error' on checkout

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to hook up Paypal payments using Paypal Payments Pro.

I'm trying to use the sandbox and live payments account and I keep getting the 'Internal Service Error' on checkout. This happens when using the form and also the checkout button.

Can anybody point me in the right direction with this? Has anybody set this up themselves?

The live account is definitely active.

Would be good to know if anybody has this running correctly.  The account is a UK Website Payments Pro Account

Comment: Think you could follow some of this and get some log files going on for us? https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% on the route cause however I ditched any customisation and rebuilt from the ground up. I imagine something changed and hasn't been updated to reflect new functionality in the code base.

There was a brief question mark over the paypal checkout button, just need to make sure you are running the latest v4.26 of webform_civicrm.